# button.setPressed(true) suddenly not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been using an emulator with the following code to press a particular button

```
redBut.performClick();
            redBut.setPressed(true);
            redBut.invalidate();
            redBut.setPressed(false);
            redBut.invalidate();
```

Using Log statements, I know for sure this piece of code is being called, so it is not that the code is being skipped over.

On my emulator, the button appeared to be pressed as if a user pressed it. Now on a real android device, the process is running but the button is unchanged. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code as follows-

```
        redBut.performClick();
        redBut.setPressed(true);
        redBut.invalidate();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {

               redBut.setPressed(false);
               redBut.invalidate();
             }
        }, 500);
```